# Get data from relationship, Laravel

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-7

I have a query where I get data using `with` , but in that table I have another relationship and I want to get data from that, and I am not sure how.

The result that I need is  between `question_topics` and `lk_answers` (there I have the names for topic_1, topic_2 ...)

[image]

```
public function index(Request $request)
{
    $query = Question::select(['id', 'free_text', 'title', 'topics_id', 'created_at']);
    $query->with('question_topics');
    $query->question_topics->with('lkp_answers');  // something like that, but this line is not working.
    return response()->json($query->paginate(5));
}
```

Comment: You forgot to show us the relationships you have set up between these 3 (2?) tables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**First**
On the model that is used for `question_topics`, you need to have the relationships for `best_match_topic`, `topic_1`, `topic_2`, and `topic_3` defined:

eg. `QuestionTopic` class

```php
class QuestionTopic {
    public function bestMatchTopic() {
        return $this->belongsTo(Topic::class, 'best_match_topic');
    }

    public function topicOne() {
        return $this->belongsTo(Topic::class, 'topic_1');
    }

    public function topicTwo() {
        return $this->belongsTo(Topic::class, 'topic_2');
    }

    public function topicThree() {
        return $this->belongsTo(Topic::class, 'topic_3');
    }

}
```

Then, if you want to get the relationship of a relationship, you can access them using the dot notation:

```php
Question::with('question_topics.bestMatchTopic', 
                   'question_topics.topicOne', 
                   'question_topics.topicTwo', 
                   'question_topics.topicThree')->get();
```

Comment: It works, thanks! Any change to get only the name from the last relationship, and not the whole array?

Comment: Yes, there is. Check out laravel resources:
https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-resources (also, if this is the answer you were looking for, please mark it as accepted. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you want question_topics data return response in json .

```
public function index(Request $request)
{
    $query = Question::select(['id', 'free_text', 'title', 'topics_id', 'created_at']);
    $query->with('question_topics');
    return response()->json($query->paginate(5));
}
```

This will give you an array of Question that have a question_topics array in each Question object. Loop iteration get like in php `$loop_raw->question_topics->best_match_topic`